# Changing position of div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have one div that holds small div and one empty space as a starting point. what i want to do is when i click on any div which is bordering the empty space then the clicked div must moves to that empty space and create another empty space which will then be occupied by any other div near it when clicked. the idea is the small div must have auto mechanism to decide where to move the movement will/must be controlled with css position. am new to jquery any suggestion will be appreciated 
here is my code i just started with two rows of div but but i can't get this right before i go to 4 rows

```
<html>
    <head> 
    <title>divs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var goTo= new Array("2,5","1,3,6","2,4,7","3,8","1,6","2,5,7","3,7,8","4,7");
        var position= new Array("0,0","0,0,60","0,0,120","0,180","0,60","0,0,120","0,60,180","0,120");
        var here=8;
        var click=true;
        $(".box").click(function(){
            if(click==true){
                click=false;
                var id=$(this).attr("id");
                id=id.split("_");
                id=parseInt(id[1]);
                id--;
                var adjacents=goTo[id];
                adjacents=adjacents.split(",");
                var move=false;
                for(i in adjacents){
                    if(adjacents[i]==here){
                        move=true;
                    }
                }
                if(move==true){
                    var movePos=position[(here-1)];
                    alert(movePos);
                        movePos=movePos.split(",")
                    $(this).animate({top:movePos[0],left:movePos[1]},1000,function(){
                        $(this).attr("id","box_"+here);
                        here=id+1;
                        click=true;
                    })
                }
                else{
                    click=true;
                }
            }


        });

    });
</script>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

                <div id="box_1" class="box" style="background:yellow;top:0px;left:0px;">
                    1
                </div>
                <div id="box_2" class="box" style="background:red;top:0px;left:60px;">
                    2
                </div>
                <div id="box_3" class="box" style="background:magenta;display:block;top:0px;left:120px;">
                    3
                </div>

                <div id="box_4" class="box" style="background:brown;top:0px;left:180px;">
                    4
                </div>
                <div id="box_5" class="box" style=" background:orange;top:60px;left:0px;">
                    5
                </div>
                <div id="box_6" class="box" style="background:pink;top:60px;left:60px;">
                    6
                </div>
                <div id="box_7" class="box" style="background:green;top:60px;left:120px;">
                    7
                </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a story-telling website, it's about asking questions. Please give it a try and come back when you have a specific problem.

Comment: Do you want to implement something like this >> http://jsfiddle.net/Bongs/S2rmx/

Answer (score 0):

HI you can proceed with creating equal number of small divs inside that big div.
And make one of the small div transparent. Next on click of some div near that transparent one
change the css of the clicked div to transparent one and vice versa. Use jQuery to swap css